# Is jquery .on faster than .click with new DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, benchmarking

I don't want to use `$(document).on('click', handler)` or `$('.class').on('click', handler)`... I prefer to use `$('.class').click();` To me it's easier to find your way in the code but I don't know if it's faster or not.

If I add a new element in the DOM like :

```
function addElementThenBindAction(){
    var html = $ ("<div><a id="#myid">Link me</a></div>");

    html.click( addElementThenBindAction() );

    $('body').append( html );
}

$('#aButtonFromDom').click(function(){
    addElementThenBundAction();
});
```

Is that faster than -

```
function addHtml(){
    var html = $ ("<div><a id="#myid">Link me</a></div>");
    $('body').append('html');
}

$(document).on('click', '#myId', function(){
    addHtml();
});
$('#aButtonFromDom').click(function(){
    addHtml();
});
```

Comment: There are big functional difference between direct and delegated event handling, with greatly different performance characteristics. That's not what you seem to ask in your title question, though?

Comment: Your `addElementThenBindAction` is infinitely recursive and will throw a stack overflow exception? Please fix your code to show us what you actually mean.

Answer (score 3):

As the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) states:

> **`.click( handler )`**
>
> This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`

In short the answer is that the `.on()` function will be "faster" than the `.click()` simply because fewer functions are being called. However the performance gain/loss that you will see is really insignificant.

Only if you would be dealing with *a lot* of elements would you *maybe* be able to see/feel the performance differences.

---

I found a jsperf that deals with this comparison along with some other comparisons - http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-versus-click/10. It's not using the newest jQuery version, but I doubt that the differences would be note worthy.